# Inconsistency in calculating the Calinski-Harabasz index for a given clustering in R

Tags: r, clustering

I am interested in determining the optimal number of clusters calculated by the PAM clustering algorithm using the Calinski-Harabasz (CH) index. To that end, I found 2 different R functions calculating CH values for a given clustering, but which returned different results: [?cluster.stats](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/fpc/html/cluster.stats.html) (in the [fpc package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fpc/index.html)), and [?index.G1](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/clusterSim/html/index.G1.html) (in the [clusterSim package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/clusterSim/index.html)).

First one is called via:

```
pam.res <- pam(dist.matrix, 2, diss=TRUE)
ch1     <- cluster.stats(dist.matrix, pam.res$clustering, silhouette=TRUE)$ch
```

Second one is called via:

```
ch2 <- index.G1(t(dataframe), pam.res$clustering, d=dist.matrix)
```

Data may be found here: [dataframe.RData](http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/327255/dataframe-RData.html), or here: [dist.matrix.RData](http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/327262/dist-matrix-RData.html) [dead links].

- **Can anybody explain the difference between these two CH index calculations to me?**

  Using `cluster.stats()`, the highest CH index is obtained for 2 clusters ($\approx32$); while using `index.G1()`, the highest CH index is obtained for 3 clusters ($\approx60$, and the value for 2 clusters is totally different from the previous, $\approx54$).
- **Which function is normally used to calculate the CH index?**

Comment: Not everyone here uses R to read in your file format. Please give your data in more convenient format (plain text, Excel?) or publish it in your question if it's not too lengthy.

Comment: You are right. Here you may find the files in txt format:
[dataframe.txt](http://uploading.com/files/31f79f42/dataframe.txt/) and [dist.matrix.txt](http://uploading.com/files/81941e36/dist.matrix.txt/)

**Loading dist.matrix.txt must be followed by converting it to _dist_ object as follows:**

`otu <- read.table("dataframe.txt")
dist.matrix <- as.dist(read.table("dist.matrix.txt"))`

Comment: This question might be better suited for the r-help listserve, where (presumably) the package maintainers would be notified of the discrepancy.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about potentially conflicting R functions.

Comment: This question requires statistical knowledge to answer, so I think it's on topic here (although contacting the package maintainers directly might be best).

Answer (score 2):

There is one method of calculating Caliński & Harabasz (1974) index for the same distance matrix, so if two R functions show different results one of them is wrong. Hence your question is **off-topic**.

- Look how Caliński & Harabasz index is calculated, in their original paper [1] or e.g. [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/clustering.evaluation.calinskiharabaszevaluation-class.html).
- Then check the source code of both R functions, find a bug and **report it to package creators**.

Here are `fpc` and `clusterSim` example sites on GitHub where you can view the source code:
https://github.com/cran/fpc/tree/master/R,
https://github.com/cran/clusterSim.

[1] Caliński, T., and J. Harabasz. "A dendrite method for cluster analysis." Communications in Statistics. Vol. 3, No. 1, 1974, pp. 1–27.

Answer (score 1):

Using a synthetic, two dimensional dataset of 200 points, euclidean distance and complete linkage I am not able to reproduce the discrepancies which you encountered.
Also the `clusterCrit` package and another implementation return the same values

```
> # fpc
> ch1 <- calinhara(X, pc, cn=max(pc))
> # clusterSim
> ch2 <- index.G1 (X,pc,d=NULL,centrotypes="centroids")
> # clusterCrit
> ch3 <- as.numeric(intCriteria(X,pc,"Calinski_Harabasz"))
> 
> cat('fpc: ', ch1, '\nclusterSim: ', ch2, '\nclusterCrit: ', ch3)
fpc:  369.0315 
clusterSim:  369.0315 
clusterCrit:  369.0315
```

Python

```
>>> itn.calinski_harabasz(X, pc)
369.0315384638188
```